# How to sort a observable array containing json objects?

Tags: knockout.js

Hello i am new in knockout javascript, I have a observablearray conataining json objets. So i am trying to sort the list of objets by a given order.

Ideclare the observablearray like yhis :

```
 var self =this;
 self.array= ko.observableArray();
```

i loop over the observablearray named "array"  with this code:

```
self.array().forEach(function(v,i){
 alert(JSON.stringify(v))
}
```

its returns me:

```
{"uuid":"74af2d36-aa47-45c5-af5d-b32c8ed56202","label":"a"}
{"uuid":"412f6222-e4c3-40a0-8a30-b1e31f53d746","label":"b"}
{"uuid":"115c9fa4-c43b-4ad0-bad7-855da850905f","label":"c"}
{"uuid":"55671032-9fc5-4361-8722-3d14abaa7d81","label":"d"}
```

I really want to have something like this into my new observableArray:

```
{"uuid":"115c9fa4-c43b-4ad0-bad7-855da850905f","label":"c"}
{"uuid":"74af2d36-aa47-45c5-af5d-b32c8ed56202","label":"a"}
{"uuid":"55671032-9fc5-4361-8722-3d14abaa7d81","label":"d"}
{"uuid":"412f6222-e4c3-40a0-8a30-b1e31f53d746","label":"b"}
```

Comment: The expected output is neither sorted based on `uuid` nor `label` (The current array you have, however, is sorted based on `label`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718699/sorting-an-observable-array-in-knockout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JS Sorting 101

To sort an array you use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You pass it a function that takes two items, `a` and `b`, and returns either `1`, `-1` or `0`.

If it returns `1` if `a` comes *after* `b`, `-1` if `a` comes *before* `b`, and `0` if there's no difference.

```js
const stringSort = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b);
const numericSort = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;

const products = [
  { name: "Bread",       cost: 3.10 },
  { name: "Almond Milk", cost: 1.30 },
  { name: "Chocolate",   cost: 2.90 }
];

console.log(
  "By name:", 
  products.sort((p1, p2) => stringSort(p1.name, p2.name))
);

console.log(
  "By cost:", 
  products.sort((p1, p2) => numericSort(p1.cost, p2.cost))
);
```

Notice that you can't pass the helpers directly to the `products.sort` method! You need another function that defines by which property we want to sort.

### Using knockout

The cool thing with knockout is that you can create a sorted version of your data that automatically updates whenever the source changes! Here's an interactive example to show what you can do.

In the example below:

- I sort inside a computed so that the UI's table updates automatically

  - when you add a product
  - when you remove a product
  - when you change the sorting method
  - when you change the sorting direction

```js
const stringCompare = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b);
const numericCompare = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;

const products = ko.observableArray([
  { name: "Bread",       cost: 3.10 },
  { name: "Almond Milk", cost: 1.30 },
  { name: "Chocolate",   cost: 2.90 }
]);

const sorters = [
  { 
    label: "By cost",
    sort: (a, b) => numericCompare(a.cost, b.cost)
  },
  { 
    label: "Alphabetically",
    sort: (a, b) => stringCompare(a.name, b.name)
  }
];

const desc = ko.observable(true);

const sorter = ko.observable(sorters[0]);
const sortMethod = ko.pureComputed(() => desc() 
  ? (a, b) => -1 * sorter().sort(a, b) 
  : sorter().sort
)

const sortedProducts = ko.pureComputed(() =>
  products().sort(sortMethod())
);

const newProduct = {
  name: ko.observable(""),
  cost: ko.observable(0)
};

const removeProduct = p => {
  products.remove(p);
}

const addProduct = () => {
  products.push({ 
    name: newProduct.name(),
    cost: +newProduct.cost() 
  });
  
  newProduct.name("");
  newProduct.cost(0);
};


ko.applyBindings({ sorters, desc, sortedProducts, newProduct, addProduct, removeProduct })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  Sort by: <select data-bind="options: sorters, value: sorter, optionsText: 'label'"></select> 
  Descending <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: desc">
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>no.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: sortedProducts">
    <tr>
     <td data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: '$' + cost.toFixed(2)"></td>
     <td>
       <button data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct">remove</button>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-bind="with: newProduct">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <input data-bind="value: name" placeholder="product name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" min="0" step="0.1" data-bind="value: cost">
       </td>
       <td>
         <button data-bind="click: addProduct">add</button>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```